# Web loses styles on Android newest WebView

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

Here is what happened, I have an Activity that contains a Webview. Then I open the same Activity from the first one, load the exact same page. Then I close this Activity, it'll cause the webview in first Activity lose all styles.

This problem is also happening on two different pages but with same styles in the web page. Whenever I finish the top Activity, the one beneath it loses all the styles that are also referenced in the page before.

This problem only happening in the latest Android WebView 53, or on Android Nougat 7.0(without WebView, but Chrome takes over).

[image: pic]

Here is the code of that activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.162/file/two.html");

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Two Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/file/test.css">

</head>
<body style="font-size: 25px;">
<div>
    <div>《登鹳雀楼》</div>
    <div class="red">白日依山尽，黄河入海流。</div>
    <div class="blue">欲穷千里目，更上一层楼。</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like with the newest WebView 54, problem solved. It's a bug from Google.